# Putting m balls to n boxes (may empty)

Tags: statistics, balls-in-bins

Suppose m balls randomly and independently put into n boxes. A box can hold more than 1 ball. Then what is the expected number of empty boxes? What is the expected number of balls that in a box with at lease one other ball?

For the first question, I don't understand why $P(X_i) = (\frac {n-1}{n})^m$ (this is the solution), where $X_i$ denotes event in which the $i^{th}$ box is empty. I think $P(X_i) = \frac {n-1}{n}$, since one ball has $n$ boxes to put in except the $i^{th}$. So where is the power of $m$ comes from?

I don't even have a clue how to solve the second question.

Comment: The power of $m$ is because there are $m$ balls.  We want *every* ball to not be placed into the $i$'th box for the $i$'th box to be empty, not just a specific ball.  Each ball individually has a probability of $\frac{n-1}{n}$ to not be placed in the $i$'th box.  Apply multiplication principle of probability and note balls are placed independently of one another.

Comment: For the second question, note that when $X_i=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if box i is empty}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ for each $i$, you have $X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$ denotes the total number of empty boxes.  Apply the linearity of expectation to see that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\sum X_i]=\sum \mathbb{E}[X_i]$

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz has already commented, the probability $\frac{n-1}n$ of a single ball not being placed in a particular box is taken to the $m$-th power because we need the probability of all $m$ balls not being placed in that particular box, and by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) we need to multiply the $m$ individual probabilities.

For the second question, for a particular ball the probability that none of the other $m-1$ balls are placed in its box is $\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{m-1}$, so the expected number of balls in a box with at least one other ball is

$$
m\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{m-1}\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Verified computationally and upvoted: (+1). (The computation is simpler than it might appear.)

Answer (score 0):

We will  verify the result by  @joriki by direct  enumeration which is
not as simple but can perhaps serve as a computational exercise.  This
serves as  a motivation to  introduce modified Stirling  numbers which
make it possible to compute the variance as well as the expectation.

We have from first principles that the expectation is given by (choose
the empty boxes first and then the ones that contain one ball only)

$$n^{-m} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} {m\choose q} q!
{m-q\brace n-k-q}_{\ge 2} 
(n-k-q)!
(m-q).$$

where the modified species of set partitions is given by
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which gives the generating function
$$\exp(u(\exp(z)-z-1))$$

and hence
$${m-q\brace n-k-q}_{\ge 2} 
= (m-q)! [z^{m-q}] \frac{(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q}}{(n-k-q)!}.$$

Substitute this into the sum to get

$$n^{-m} m! \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\sum_{q=0}^{\min(n-k,m)} {n-k\choose q}
(m-q) [z^{m-q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q}.$$

We split this into two pieces, getting for the first piece

$$n^{-m} m! m \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\sum_{q=0}^{\min(n-k,m)} {n-k\choose q}
[z^{m-q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q}.$$

Now for the coefficient we put
$$[z^{m-q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m-q+1}} (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q} \; dz$$

and observe that  this is zero when  $q\gt m$ so we may  set the upper
limit of the inner sum to $n-k,$ getting for the inner sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} z^q
(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} (\exp(z)-1)^{n-k} \; dz.$$

This yields for the outer sum
$$n^{-m} m! m\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^{n-k} \; dz
\\ = n^{-m} m! m\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} \exp(nz) \; dz
= n^{-m} m! m \frac{n^m}{m!} = m.$$

This can also be obtained by inspection because when we move $m$ to the front what remains is a classification according to the number of empty boxes, boxes with one ball, and boxes with more than one ball, and these are all the probabilities, so they must sum to one.

We continue with the second piece which is

$$- n^{-m} m! \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\sum_{q=0}^{\min(n-k,m)} q {n-k\choose q}
[z^{m-q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q}.$$

This time we get for the inner sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} 
\sum_{q=1}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} q z^q
(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q} \; dz
\\ = (n-k) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} 
\sum_{q=1}^{n-k} {n-k-1\choose q-1} z^q
(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-q} \; dz
\\ = (n-k) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k-1} {n-k-1\choose q} z^{q+1}
(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-k-1-q} \; dz
\\ = (n-k) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}} 
(\exp(z)-1)^{n-k-1}
\; dz.$$

This yields for the outer sum of the second piece

$$- n^{-m} m! 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (n-k)
(\exp(z)-1)^{n-k-1}
\; dz
\\ = - n^{-m} m! n
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^{n-k-1}
\; dz
\\ = - n^{-m} m! n
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m}} 
\exp((n-1)z) \; dz
= - n^{-m} m! n
\frac{(n-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\\ = - n^{-(m-1)} m (n-1)^{m-1}.$$

Collecting the two pieces we finally obtain

$$m - n^{-(m-1)} m (n-1)^{m-1}
\\ = m \left(1 - \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{m-1}\right).$$

These data were verified with the following Maple program.

```
B :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local d, mset, ind, res;

    res := 0;

    for ind from n^m to 2*n^m-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, n);
        d := [seq(d[v], v=1..m)];

        mset := convert(d, `multiset`);
        mset := select(p->p[2] >= 2, mset);

        res := res +
        add(p[2], p in mset);
    od;

    res;
end;
```

A similar yet somewhat simpler calculation can be found at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585089/).